# Ssh timeout in Node.JS v12.14./12.16.1

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, meteor, ssh2

I have a meteor based nodejs application. In this application, I open multiple parallel ssh connections upto 200 max. I use nodejs based node-ssh library to establish ssh connections (Node-ssh library in-turn uses nodejs based ssh2 library). I use nodejs based async library to run ssh tasks in parallel. I run 200 async tasks, via async library, to open 200 parallel ssh connections.

When I run the application with node v12.0.0, my application runs properly. But when I run the application with node v12.14.0 or v12.16.1 (meteor uses node v12.14.0 or v12.16.1, so I have to test with these node versions), I get lot of ssh timeouts and I can't complete my activity.

I can tweak the ssh timeout settings and number of parallel ssh connections to make application work properly with node v12.14.0/12.16.1. However this decreases performance significantly.

My question is, has something changed with relation to ssh/async-tasks in node v12.14.0 or v12.16.1 that I cant run 200 ssh tasks in parallel? Iam wondering that behaviour of worker threads in higher versions of nodejs has probably changed, so Iam not able to open 200 parallel ssh connections. Any suggestions on what the problem is or how I can debug it.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read the [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a proper question. Afterwards, please edit your question accordingly, so others can actually help you to solve the issue.

Comment: @Jankapunkt I have edited the question. I can't post code in the question as it is complicated. Do you think I need to further edit my question? If so, any suggestions?

Comment: @ViSe Code is king around here. Complicated or not, it's hard for us to debug your words. If you don't want to post the code, you could look at the NodeJS release notes to see what has changed, and that might give you an answer